# <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" /> not working for me

Tags: android

I would like to develop an application where I can direct call a phone number. But in my AndroidManifest.xml, there is an error in my

`<uses-permission android:name= "android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />`

it says that "Permission exists without corresponding hardware  tag" and so I added the tag. But still the CALL_PHONE in

```
"if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) is an error"
```

what should I do?

```
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,new String[](Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE));
}
```

I already tried doing it in a new activity but still the same result.

Comment: What do you mean by "is an error"?

Comment: Might be this solve issue https://googlesamples.github.io/android-custom-lint-rules/checks/PermissionImpliesUnsupportedChromeOsHardware.md.html

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.